# Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'User?'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I try to perform a segue from a button to a specific userID chatController with this code:

```
@IBAction func toChatPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let user = jobDetails?.userID
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
}
```

But its giving me **Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'User?'** as an error...

chatController.user:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        navigationItem.title = user?.name
        observeMessages()
    }
}
```

I get the userID passed from a tableViewCell and is saved in a structure

```
struct JobDetails {
    var jobDetail: String
    var userName: String
    var userImage: UIImage?
    var jobImage: UIImage?
    var downloadURL: String?
    var userLocation: String
    var userID: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `chatController`, the property `user` is of type `User`, i.e.

```
var user: User? {
    ....
}
```

Now, in `toChatPressed(_:)` method, you're setting the value of `userID` to `chatController's` `user` as evident from your code,

```
let user = jobDetails?.userID
```

Here `userID` is a `String?`. So, `user` in the above code is of type `String?`

```
chatLogController.user = user
```

In the above code, you are assigning `user` (of type `String?`) to `chatLogController.user` (of type `User`). This is what your error means.

**Solution:**

There can be 2 options to resolve the issue.

**1.** Either create a property `userID` of type `String?` in `chatLogController`, i.e.

```
var userID: String?
```

Now, set it from `toChatPressed(_:)` like,

```
chatLogController.userID = jobDetails?.userID
```

**2.** Or, you can create a `User` object using `jobDetails` in `toChatPressed(_:)` and then set it to `chatLogController's` `user`, i.e.

```
let user = User(jobDetails) //this depends upon the how you've defined User
chatLogController.user = user
```

In case you still have any confusion, feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning `JobDetails.userID: String?` to `ChatLogController.user: User?`

See your code:

```swift
    let user = jobDetails?.userID
    …
    chatLogController.user = user
```

You have to map the `jobDetails?.userID: String` to a `User?`.

Comment: i honetsly don't know if I fully understand you, sorry im new to this... could you maybe give me the full solution please?

Comment: because that's what my question is.. how am I doing this

Comment: @DwallaT, you cannot assign "String" value to "User" value. In your ChatLogController, make the property "user" of type String

Answer (score -1):

Inside of your `struct JobDetails`, add a new field containing the `User` object:

```swift
struct JobDetails {
    var jobDetail: String
    var userName: String
    var userImage: UIImage?
    var jobImage: UIImage?
    var downloadURL: String?
    var userLocation: String
    var userID: String?
    var user: User? // <-- New field
}
```

Whenever you create a new `JobDetails`, pass the `User` object to the `user` field.

Now, you function can use the `user` field instead of the `userID` field:

```swift
@IBAction func toChatPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let user = jobDetails?.user // <-- user of type User? instead of userID of type String?
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
}
```